# How could I make the attack random every time you enter "hit"?

Tags: python

At the start, when you type "hit" for the first time it is random but afterwards it gives you the same results as before...

```
import time
import random
while yourhealthpoints  >=  0 and (gargoil):
    attack = input("Type hit to attack your opponent")
    if attack == "hit" or attack == "HIT" or attack == "Hit":
        gargoilhealthpoints = gargoilhealthpoints - yourattack
        print("You hit the gargoil for %s health-points" % yourattack)
        time.sleep(2)
        if gargoilhealthpoints <= 0:
            gargoil = False
            print("You defeated the gargoil!")
        if gargoil:
            yourhealthpoints = yourhealthpoints - gargoilattack
            print("The gargoil hit you for %s health-points, you have %s health-points left..." %(gargoilattack, yourhealthpoints))
            if yourhealthpoints <= 0:
                print("You were killed by: GARGOIL...")
```

Answer (score 2):

I cannot see where the random attack is generated but if you have the variable `yourattack`, make sure you do `yourattack = random.randint(attack_range)` AFTER you put `while yourhealthpoints  >=  0 and (gargoil):`

Otherwise it will generate a random number once and use that continuously.
Also to make a tad bit shorter, instead of

```
attack = input("Type hit to attack your opponent")
if attack == "hit" or attack == "HIT" or attack == "Hit":
    gargoilhealthpoints = gargoilhealthpoints - yourattack
```

You can do

```
attack = input("Type hit to attack your opponent")
attack = attack.lower()
if attack == "hit":
    gargoilhealthpoints = gargoilhealthpoints - yourattack
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped a lot. I accidentally forgot to put the beginning in.                                                                                                             Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @Hermes of course! Glad I could help